# Mosaic and feather in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, image-mosaic

Am trying to mosaic 11 scenes in ArcMap but my results are not smooth.

How can I mosaic and at the same time feather in ArcMap 10.1 to make sure the brightness is uniform.

I have EVI geotiff scenes

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [Color Balance Mosaic Dataset tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0017000000sw000000) (also available as option if you right click the mosaic dataset in the Catalog > Enhance > Color Balance).

Check the tool's help page to make sure your mosaic meets the requirements before running it.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the generate seamlines tool, then turn the seamline features into graphics, then clip each image by the seamline, then place the images in the same draw order as the seamlines and use the Blend tool, under image analysis. That should produce a good result.